# finding member in nested lists netlogo

Tags: list, nested, netlogo, member

i'm trying to solve a problem in netlogo that has me stuck for a while now. i've got two lists (of turtles i've collaborated with and of "successful"/"unsuccessful" judgments). the two lists are mapped like so [[(turtle 10) "successful"] [(turtle 11) "unsuccessful"] with the following:

```
let general-history (map list collaborators my-success)
```

where the collaborators are the who numbers and my-success is a string (either "successful" or "unsuccessful")

now, i would like to check whether a turtle has, in its general-history list, at least one successful and one unsuccessful collaborator, to be able to proceed. this is where i've gotten to:

```
ifelse not empty? general-history and member? "successful " last general-history and member? "unsuccessful" last general-history
```

i know this is wrong because *last* here implies that i'll be looking only at the last list of general-history (i.e., [] [] [this one]). what i want it to do is assess whether there are at least two lists (one with "successful" as index 1 and one with "unsuccessful" as index 1) in the whole general-history nested list.

would foreach work better here or is it possible to still use member? but with some kind of element + list indexing? thank you very much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, you can use `map` to create a list of all the `last` items (success or not) and then apply `member?` to that list. Here is a complete model example that constructs some test data and the applies this approach.

```
to testme
  clear-all
  ; create some test data
  create-turtles 10
  let collaborators sort n-of 3 turtles
  let list-both (map list collaborators (list "yes" "no" "no"))
  print list-both
  ; check condition
  print member? "yes" map last list-both
end
```